# How to fix type unknown cannot be used as an index type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that returns a `Set`

And i need to iterate this set, but I found out that Set is not iterable so I convert it to array and now I'm getting this error `type unknown cannot be used as an index type`

Here is my code

```
let chosenDenominators = Array.from(MyLogic.randomUniqueDenominators(denominators, 3));
    for (let i = 0; i < chosenDenominators.length; i++) {
        console.log(denominators[chosenDenominators[i]]) //------- error here ---------
    }
```

How to fix this issue?

EDIT:

```
static randomUniqueDenominators(denominators: number[], count: number) {
    let nums = new Set();
    let numerator = 0;

    while ((nums.size < count)) {
        numerator = Math.floor(Math.random() * denominators.length);
        nums.add(numerator);
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: The function `randomUniqueDenominators` is returning Set<unknown>

Comment: But I need to get values from another array using the set values

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - how is the Set created?

Comment: I made an edit to the question please take a look

Comment: I think i fixed it with this: `let nums = new Set<number>();`